# Create new variable whose values should be square of difference between imdbrating and imdbvotes in python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code to calculate the square difference between `imdbRating` and `imdbVotes`

```py
imdb_data['imdbVotes'] = imdb_data['imdbVotes'].astype(int)  
imdb_data['imdbRating'] = imdb_data['imdbRating'].astype(int)

imdb_data['new'] = imdb_data['imdbRating'] - imdb_data['imdbVotes']
```

This is the error I got with Python 3.7.0 + pandas 0.23.4:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

(`imdb_data` is a dataframe and the column-names referenced do exist)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/2750819.

Comment: `imdb_data` is not a dataframe if that's the error you're getting?

Comment: no that is not the error . imdb_data i converted it into thr required datattypes . I guess its because of the missing values in the dataset or its not cleaned .

Comment: Can you provide sample dataframe with values, so that others can copy paste and check your problem ?

Comment: here is the link to the entire dataset  (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KvWzmqLaA_ZlKoKRSz0V1ycm4FIOdICQ) @PrinceFrancis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns `imdbRating, imdbVotes` should be of datatype `float`. So convert them to `float` from `string`. Then do your calculations.

```py
imdb_data = pd.read_csv('IMDB_data.csv', sep=',',encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
imdb_data['imdbRating'] = pd.to_numeric(imdb_data['imdbRating'], errors='coerce', downcast='float')
imdb_data['imdbVotes'] = pd.to_numeric(imdb_data['imdbVotes'], errors='coerce', downcast='float')
imdb_data['new'] = imdb_data['imdbRating'] - imdb_data['imdbVotes']
imdb_data.head()
```

output is
[image: output as image]

```
    Plot    Title   imdbVotes   Poster  imdbRating  Genre   imdbID  Year    Language    new
0   Despite his tarnished reputation after the eve...   The Dark Knight Rises   2679.0  http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk4ODQz...   75.0    Action, Thriller    tt1345836   2012    English     -2604.0
1   0   0   0.0     0   0.0     0   0   0   0   0.0
2   Based on the novel written by Stephen Chbosky,...   The Perks of Being a Wallflower     1270.0  http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzIxOTQy...   71.0    Drama, Romance  tt1659337   2012    English     -1199.0
3   Mike Lane is a thirty-year old living in Tampa...   Magic Mike  2580.0  http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQzMDMz...   51.0    Comedy, Drama   tt1915581   2012    English     -2529.0
4   When Bond's latest assignment goes gravely wro...   Skyfall     1807.0  http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAyODkz...   68.0    Action, Thriller    tt1074638   2012    English     -1739.0
```

Comment: I tried the above code and still encountered the same error  , also tried this line of code " imdb_data['imdbRating'] = imdb_data['imdbRating'].astype(float)" which is also getting the same error saying string indices must be integers @PrinceFrancis

Comment: What is your python and pandas version ?

Comment: Python 3.7.0 and pandas: 0.23.4

Comment: I am using pandas `0.25.3` and python `3.7.5`. It works here. I edited my answer with output.

Comment: updated the pandas version and now it works

Comment: but when i tried to get the square of the 'new' column . I'm getting the error saying series not callable

Comment: how you tried ? Use like these `imdb_data['square'] = imdb_data['new']**2`